# Android / PHP: Display “Data successfully save” after save input data from android to MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to ask something regarding my project. In my App, there's an EditText that need to be input by the user and after that the user must click button "save" to save the input data to mysql database. I do it successfully, which means the data has been saved.

But the problem is, the android apps don't show the message "Data saved". This message I wrote it PHP.

Below is my code:

JAVA

```
private void createTask(final String task_name, final String badgeid) {

StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_ADD_TASK, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
        Map<String,String>parms=new HashMap<String, String>();
        parms.put("task_name",task_name);
        parms.put("badgeid",badgeid);
        return parms;
    }
};
RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once "../config/configPDO.php";

$task_name = $_POST['task_name'];
$badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO report (task_name, badgeid, report_date, report_status) VALUES('$task_name','$badgeid', NOW(), 'Pending')";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

if($query){
    echo "Data Save!";
}else{
    echo "Error!! Not Saved";
}

?>
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from server to Application. API is compressed of Request and Response. As per your example you are sending parameters to API and API is not returning anything from Server. Instead of echo try to return response back to Application. In app onResponse you need to handle messages came from server. There you can show toast message or anything you need to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Toast your response in `onResponse` Callback of `StringRequest`

Like,

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Just Replace onResponse method of Response.Listener<String> with this code.

Comment: Yes. Thanks mate